# subscribe mail isn't working in magento header

Tags: magento, email, newsletter

I have disabled this part from newsletter.xml

```
<reference name="left">
      <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

and directly using this part  in the header

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Join') ?>" class="button"><p>JOIN</p></button>
</form>
```

from the code of subscribe.phtml. But it does't subscribe email. What I did wrong or is that a SMTP problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I just Got it from Magento Stack Exchange.

Replace

```
<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true)) ?>
```